# Three way interaction and ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have two factors (A and B), 5 conditions and 3 groups.I used repeated measure of ANOVA. There is a main effect of factor A and B, significant interaction between A and B (2- way interaction) and significant interaction between factors and groups (3 way interaction).I also carried out post-hoc analysis and the result is group 2 performance is significantly poorer than group and 1 and 3.
 Since there is 3-way interaction,do i have to do ANOVA to see in which condition there was group differences?